# Strange DropDown in "Tutorial Query - Discover Visual Query" for 2sxc module

Tags: dotnetnuke-module, 2sxc

I am testing the : 2sxcApp_TutorialQuery-DiscoverVisualQuery_01.00.00

my dnn and 2sxc module versions:

- dnn - 08.00.02
- 2sxc - 08.04.05

If I edit configuration for module, there is a DropDown for SortOrder field,
and I like that this stay this way.

[(screen1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG2kr.jpg)

But the problem is that if I go to look application definition,
tere is no such dropdown field. There is only string field of unknown type.

[(screen2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFjgU.jpg)

How is this posible, or from where aplication get this dropdown values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a left-over of older times. In the old days, the dropdown items were in a special field which was part of the "String" definition. This had to be moved in 2sxc 8, because otherwise the "String" had many fields which never really applied. Now the values are in the "string-dropdown" - but the UI still shows the old values till you manually add new values to string-dropdown.

I hope we can update the sample soon.

Comment: Do you know version when this change happened?

Comment: I believe the full change happened in 8.0 as we went from webforms to angularjs editing

Comment: btw: I just uploaded a fixed demo app